# Spring http status code - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant

Tags: spring, http-status-codes, spring-rest

I'm using The spring rest-template for calling the rest URL , I get a response from the server but the http-status code is invalid and the Spring throws , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant . Due to this exception the application is failing , this looks like a bug in the Spring code . Since the http status code received is not in the list spring framework is looking forit failed . Is there a Spring way to handle it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring seems to use the standard status code in their enum. You can find the status codes here: `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`.

Probably the API you're querying is not returning a standard HTTP Status code. Your best bet is to create a custom error handler, like this:

```
var r = new RestTemplate();

r.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
  @Override
  public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return response.getRawStatusCode() != 550;
  }

  @Override
  public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
    // Do nothing?
  }
});

var response = r.exchange("https://httpbin.org/status/550", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

System.out.println(response.getStatusCodeValue());
```

What we're saying is basically if the status code returned is 550 (not a standard code), we don't want to do anything about it.

Another option you have is, of course, to catch the exception and do something about it.

```
try {
  // Call the API here
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // Do something about it here...
}
```